# Create video asset to google ads

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-ads-api

I have successfully uploaded the video to my channel with YouTube API and used this video as an ad asset.

but,I hope to upload video materials to Ad Storage Channel

[image]

I tried to specify the ChannelID when uploading the video, but it did not work
It uploads the video to my Youtube channel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7L4C.png)

Is there any way to upload the video to this channel?

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.